# What is the way of making "Http.post" call in elm

Tags: elm

I have used the http post in elm in following manner but it is not working and on server side I am getting the empty body.
Can anybody tell me what is wrong with this code.this is the code of my command module

```
module SignupForm.Commands exposing (..)

import Http exposing(..)
import Json.Decode as Decode exposing (field)
import SignupForm.Models exposing (..)
import SignupForm.Messages exposing (..)
import Json.Encode as Encode
import Debug exposing (log)




memberDecoder : Decode.Decoder UserDetails
memberDecoder =
    Decode.map4 UserDetails
        (field "fname" Decode.string)
        (field "lname" Decode.string)
        (field "email" Decode.string)
        (field "password" Decode.string)



saveUrl : String
saveUrl =
   "http://localhost:4000/userSignup"


saveRequest : UserDetails -> Http.Request UserDetails
saveRequest d =
    Http.request


        { body = memberEncoded d |> Http.jsonBody
        , expect = Http.expectJson memberDecoder
        , headers = defaultRequestHeaders
        , method = "POST"
        , timeout = Nothing
        , url = saveUrl
        , withCredentials = False
        }



defaultRequestHeaders : List Header
defaultRequestHeaders =
    [ Http.header "Content-Type"  "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    ]

fetchAll : UserDetails -> Cmd Msg
fetchAll data =
    saveRequest data
        |> Http.send OnSignUp


memberEncoded : UserDetails -> Encode.Value
memberEncoded data =
    let
        list =
            [ ( "fname", Encode.string data.fname )
            , ( "lname", Encode.string data.lname )
            , ( "email", Encode.string data.email )
            , ( "password", Encode.string data.password )
            ]
    in
        list
            |> Encode.object
```

Answer (score 1):

You are posting json, but declaring that you are sending formdata.

Try removing:

```
defaultRequestHeaders : List Header
defaultRequestHeaders =
    [ Http.header "Content-Type"  "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    ]
```

(Note that expectJson will add `Http.header "Content-Type"  "application/json"` automatically for you

Comment: you are right I have tried without  "defaultRequestHeaders" but it is not working